# Can you get blackboard letter N, R, etc., symbols for mathematical notation?

Tags: macos, font, internationalization, unicode

The Special Characters palette includes many mathematical symbols, but I cannot seem to find [blackboard bold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold) versions of N, R, and Z, which are commonly used to denote the set of (respectively) the natural numbers, real numbers, and integers.

Right now, when I use the Special Characters palette and configure the Unicode section, and then look for the mathematical symbols, I find blackboard versions of A, B, and others, but inexplicably, certain characters including the N, R, and Z are *missing*. Here is a screenshot to show what I mean:

[image]

Are the blackboard characters available somehow, and I am missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N is at U+2115, R is at U+211D... just as described in the wikipedia article you linked to.  Odd that they aren't in the normal ABC order.  But, they are there.

[image: screen shot of character viewer]

Comment: You're right! The fact they're out of order really threw me, and the way the N, R, Z are buried in with other symbols makes them hard to notice even when looking at 2115 etc. Well, thanks for solving that.

Answer (score 2):

They are available for use directly without any configuration and here they are (and they are in a different Unicode range and hence missing from the range you posted):

- ℕ (hex 2115)
- ℝ (hex 211D)
- ℤ (hex 2124)

To type them, you might want to enable Unicode Hex Input and then hold the option key down while typing the 4 hex numbers above. Once you have them, you can add them to your favorites in the Special Characters palette (Control+Command+Space) or make keyboard spelling corrections (System Preferences, Keyboard, Text) to convert other abbreviations to these automatically.

Comment: Thank you for making this comment; I was unaware of the Unicode Hex Input keyboard option in the input sources.  This was a useful tip.